# Динамическое отображение данных

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails

Начал изучать AngularJS в связке в Rails 4.
В контроллере

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { @articles = current_user.articles.all }
      format.json { render json: current_user.articles.all }
    end
  end
  ...
```

Сервер по адрессу http://ip:3000/articles.json отдает нормальный json. Во вьюхе:

```
<div ng-controller="articleController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="article in articles">
      <b>{{article.title}}</b>
      <p>{{article.text}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module('myApp', []).controller('articleController', function($scope) {

    $http.get('/articles.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.articles = data;
      alert(data);
    });

    /*
    $scope.articles = [{
      title: 'First title',
      text: 'First text',
    },{
      title: 'Second Title',
      text: 'Second Text',
    }]
    */
  });
</script>
```

На тех данных которые закомментированны все работает, а на тех которые должны приходить с сервера нет, в чем проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите структуру JSON ответа `$scope.articles = data`.

Comment: Подозреваю, что там просто другой JSON: `{ "articles": [{...}, {...}, ...] }`

Comment: смотрите ошибки в консоли браузера

Answer (score 1):

Не силён в ангуларе, но после беглого ознакомления с [документацией](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) рискну предположить что неверна попытка обработки ответа.

> get(url, [config]);
>
> Returns `HttpPromise` Future object

У промиса я [не вижу](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) метода `success`.

Видимо, должно быть так:

```
 $http.get('/articles.json').then(
  function(data) {
    $scope.articles = data;
    alert(data);
  }
);
```

**UPD**
Посмотрел документацию старых версий. `success` был заменён на `then` в версии [1.4.4](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/docs/api/ng/service/$http):

> The `$http` legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `then` method instead. If `$httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions` is set to false then these methods will throw `$http/legacy` error.

Answer (score 1):

$http.get возвращает http response объект, в свойстве **response.data** которого содержаться необходимые данные.

```
$http.get('/articles.json').then(function(response) {
   $scope.articles = response.data;
   alert($scope.articles);
});
```